# Help! Trying to install new ceiling lights

Tags: electrical

I’m trying to wire 3 LED ceiling lights in my office. I’m a DIY guy but just for basic electrical stuff.

In the center of the drawing I made is where the old light used to be. My house is old and I live in Indiana. I was expecting a basic wiring because that’s easy, but seeing all these other wires is confusing me and I rather do this correctly than wing it. What are all these wires doing in here and are they correctly wired? What schematic do I use to wire the 3 new LED lights from this box where the cheap old light used to be? I want the office switch to control all 3 of these new lights. Do I simply wire the light’s Hot to the group of Hot (top left corner of the box)? Is it ok there the group of Hot wires has 1 random wire attached to nothing? Please help!

Thanks[image]

Comment: Neutrals are not switched so they do not connect to switch

Comment: where is the cable where the power comes in from the breaker

Comment: Normally green indicates ground. A "wire" has a single conductor, while a "cable" contains multiple wires inside it. Your neutral and ground colors on your diagram look the same in your photo.

Answer (score 1):

> What are all these wires doing in here and are they correctly wired?

Nope.

Hopefully your diagram is inaccurate.

The next step is to open up the office light switch.  You'll need to find out if there are more than 2 wires as shown in your diagram.

Ultimately, the switch must be connected to the power source.  If the power source is "top left corner" then it's already connected to the wrong wires.  You would have to rearrange that.

If your house does not have ground wires for this circuit, you need to consider NEC 410.44.  Under that rule it would be illegal to install any luminaire that has exposed conductive parts.  Those LEDs would have to be completely glass/plastic/ceramic on the outside.  Alternatively, it might be possible to upgrade the circuit breaker to GFCI, but that depends on the age and type of panelboard.  If these conditions can't be met then I would advise against installing those lights.

To be even more specific, those options only apply to "replacement luminaires".  That means you could install 1 replacement LED, not 3.

Getting slightly off topic, but the other exception under 410.44 is to run a new EGC.  This is where we get into "branch circuit extensions" and adding new LEDs where there were no lights before.  If you want to add 3 LEDs without rewiring the whole circuit, then the new EGC is a minimum requirement.  Depending on your system, this might mean running wire from the office ceiling all the way to the electrical or plumbing service entrance.

Some jurisdictions are also adopting NEC 210.12 for branch circuit extensions.

Comment: "EGC" = Equipment Ground Conductor, connected directly or indirectly back to the ground in your electrical panel.